# jboss 5.1.0 integration with jdk6 and spring2.5.1 compatible?

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss

is jbos5.1.0 compatible with jdk6 and spring2.5.X.
I am also integraion acegi security and not spring security 3.0 as i am using spring 2.5.0?
IS jboss 5.1.0 comaptible with spribng3.0 andjdk6 ?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Do you have reason to believe otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago, I've tried JBoss 5 with Spring 2.5.6 and couldn't deploy my application, because of [this bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5120). The comments on the issue, mention the problem only happens with EJB, but my application didn't make use of EJB and it was packed as a war.

According to the JIRA, this was fixed in spring 3.0RC1, but I haven't tried it (for now, I gave up updating to a new version of JBoss).

Comment: spring 3.0.5 jboss5.0 ga,jdk6 & spring security 3.0.5 perfectly working